# Why a few this same components works differently in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following component named Card:

```
<article className={styles.card_container}>
        <input type="checkbox" className={styles.checkbox} onClick={setCheckbox}/>
        <div className={styles.text_container} id="txt_container">
            <span>
                {props.number}
            </span>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Which should display checkbox, without the tick - container to check or not, with background colors, depends on this checkbox is checked or not.
For example, when unchecked this should has red color, but when checked - black.
For this, I decided to use state:

```
const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);

const setCheckbox = (e) => {
    if (isChecked===true){
        setChecked(false);
        document.getElementById("txt_container").style.backgroundColor="#a81616";
    }else {
        setChecked(true);
        document.getElementById("txt_container").style.backgroundColor="#000";
    }
}
```

I wanted to create a few this type of components so I decided to map this with information from array:

```
{data.map(element=>
                <Card number={element.option} key={element.option}/>)
            }
```

(Where data is an array with object with numbers, Card is created components with code above).
The problem is that, when I "check" other components, it change color only at first.
Why did it happen? I appreciate for any help.

And there some css code:

```
    .card_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid #50bcf2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I would like to do this by js, is there other way to do this (not by css)? Or maybe can I inject background color provided by props from for example an array to Card component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style` attribute on react component

```
<div className={styles.text_container} style={{backgroundColor: isChecked? #a81616 : #000}}>
```

your code doesnt work, because ID is supposed to be unique and you are only selecting first occurence... if you want to work with DOM in react, dont use `getElementByID` and use `useRef()` from react. Its more "reactish" way how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works. Have a nice day!